# Where should I install third-party binary-only programs?

Tags: software-installation

I have a third-party binary-only program that only comes with `.sh` instalation script (not even a `.deb` package) I’d like to install on my system. (PyCharm, if this is relevant.)

I think have basically two options, either install it to `/opt` or `~/PyCharm`.

Where should I install it? Are there any relevant pros or cons?

Installing to `/opt` will require granting `sudo` to the installation script. And what if the app wants to update itself? Worst case, I’d have to run it with `gksudo`.

Answer (score 4):

For PyCharm in particular, if you're the only user on the system in question I'd just install it in `~/PyCharm`. As you point out it will make upgrades easier.

To answer your question more generally, there are indeed pros and cons to consider:

- installing in `/opt` with `root` ownership typically gives access to all users of the system (that's the way most installers work);
- if your `/home` is a separate file system, installing in `/opt` avoids taking up space there;
- installing in `/opt` also avoids taking up space in your backups;
- installing in your home directory means the software is writeable by default (which simplifies upgrades).

Regarding the latter point, if you're the only user on the system, there's nothing stopping you from installing in `/opt` and `chown`ing the software's installation directory to yourself: that way, you keep it out of `/home`, and it's still trivially upgradable.